# Jest Mock Errors with ES Modules for i18next

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking, es6-modules, i18next

I have problems configuring mocks for `i18next`. I'm running Jest with node's `--experimental-vm-modules` flag. (calling `node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js`).

this Error happens:
`Must use import to load ES Module: /App/Mocks/i18nextMock.js`

my test configurations, suits & mocks are as follows:

jest.config.js

```js
export default async () => {
    return {
        verbose: true,
        testEnvironment:'jsdom',
        transform: {
            '\\.jsx?$': ['babel-jest', { configFile: '<rootDir>/Command/Test/BabelConfig.json') }],
        },
        moduleNameMapper: {
            "^.+\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "babel-jest",
            "i18next": '<rootDir>/App/Mocks/i18nextMock.js'),
        },
        setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/Command/Test/EnzymeConfig.js')],
        globals: {
            NODE_ENV: "test"
        },
    };
};
```

BabelConfig.json

```json
{
    "presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env", {
            "targets": { "browsers": ["last 2 chrome versions"] },
            "useBuiltIns": "usage",
            "corejs": "3.6.5"
        }],
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }],
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"
    ]
}
```

/App/Mocks/i18nextMock.js

```js
import { jest } from "@jest/globals";

const i18next = jest.createMockFromModule("i18next");

// this is all I need from i18next for now
i18next.getFixedT = () => () => "";


export default i18next;
```

my test suite for store.js which uses i18next:

sotre.test.js

```js
import store from "../store";

jest.mock("i18next");

describe("A suite for store", () => {
    it("should create new store", () => {
        const store = new store();
        expect(store).toBeInstanceOf(store);
    });
});
```

store.js

```js
import i18next from 'i18next';

class store {
    //...
    constructor(){
      this.t = i18next.getFixedT(null, "myPageDictionary");
      this.name = this.t("sample message");
      //...
    }
    //...
}
export default store;
```

again as mentioned above, when running `npm run test` I get the following Error:

`Must use import to load ES Module: /App/Mocks/i18nextMock.js`

I've tried changing the way I export in i18nextMock.js

from `export default i18next;`

to `module.exports = i18next;`

but the Error changes to:

`SyntaxError: The requested module 'i18next' does not provide an export named 'default'`

I've also tried to create a manual-mock by avoiding `jest.createMockFromModule` which was to no avail as well.

the following change

i18nextMock.js

```
- const i18next = jest.createMockFromModule("i18next"); // removed
+ const i18next = {}; // added

i18next.getFixedT = () => () => "";

export default i18next;
```

caused the following Error:

`ReferenceError: require is not defined`

I'm using ESModules in all parts of my project & I've decided to use `--experimental-vm-modules` flag to run test commands. However, mocking third party libs like this one seems to be troublesome.

I would appreciate any help or workarounds for this to get rid of Errors & make jest work correctly by mocking external libs. Thanks in advance.